# Windows V4 Driver - Multiple Copies

Tags: windows, printing, driver, xps

We are developing a Windows V4 raster based driver for a wide format device, which doesn't support multiple copies in hardware. So if the user selects multiple copies then this must be performed by the driver.

I've tried modifying the source GPD to disable collate, and I hoped that the Windows printing pipeline might then play the job as many times as required, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

I can't find much about this on the Microsoft sites, and it's not clear to me if we need a new filter in the XPS pipeline to replay the print job as many times as required or if it is better done in some alternative way.

If anyone has a suggestion of the best route to allow a XPS driver to handle multiple copies in software.

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 2):

Fiddling with GPD isn't going to achieve much - you can enable or disable features, but that won't actually add support for the features - you will still need to implement them yourself in the pipeline.

You will need a new filter that performs the copies in the job. I would recommend creating a part-based filter that copies the parts as needed before sending them to the IXpsDocumentConsumer interface. A couple of points to keep in mind:

1. Copies may be specified at any level of the printticket, in JobCopiesAllDocuments, DocumentCopiesAllPages, or PageCopies.
2. As a result, a robust filter will need to perform the necessary copying at each level.
3. Only a single IFixedDocumentSequence may be sent, so if the FixedDocumentSequence ticket indicates copying must occur via the JobCopiesAllDocuments entry, you must make copies of all the IFixedDocuments, not the IFixedDocumentSequence itself.